# PHP - specific query

Tags: php

I have a problem. I dont really dont know exactly wat to do. I cant seem to get how to limit my query.

For example.

`t1` has 5 columns . . .

```
   username, itemA, itemB, itemC, itemD
```

The colums itemA to itemD are primary keys from `t2`. `t2` has 2 columns, ID and items.

`t2` contains ID, items. it has 4 rows under ITEMS. . .`

```
  shirt,socks,short,pants.
```

the username dadi in `t1` has 2 entries shirt for itemA and socks for itemB. the remaining 2 fields is empty. How do I perform a query that tells me the last that the username Dadi has 2 missing entry short and pants?

For further explanation.. i want to perform a query that will display the $rows for itemC and itemD as short and pants because they are missing in t1. The result will display short and pants and not the first two because user 'Dadi' has shirt and socks already as itemA and itemB.

Comment: This question really isn't clear. Please edit and make it more explanatory.

Comment: make a fiddle on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: if user has missing entry then if u do outer join one of the table will have null value for the corresponding id

Answer (score 0):

well you would check if the field is null/ empty depending what your default is defined in table. This could be done a few ways, either get the row for Dadi and then use PHP to check if the column is NULL OR have a select statement that selects all users that are missing an value for itemC and itemD :

select username from t1 where t1.itemC is null and t1.itemD is null

Comment: as an added note if the relation is 1:many as in 1 user has 4 items then you shouln't have your primary key in the user table, each item should have 1 column called userID or similar that connects it to the user.

Comment: I was just going to mention that.  It's more complicated to enforce constraints with the people linking to the items than the other way around.  (Unless one's been going crazy with `check` constraints -- which might not even work in MySQL; i forget -- the only thing really preventing duplicate items and such is the PHP code.  And we all know how rock-solid everyone makes their PHP code.  :P )

Comment: well i suppose it is and it isn't if you a person can only ever have 4 items then i guess the OPs design works but it doesn't all for you to say add another item to the person without changing the structure of the persons table. Say you want to now start storing itemE which is if the person has shoes

Comment: well, the query will display or suggest u r missing to items which is exactly shorts and pants. Its telling me that my user 'dadi' must insert short and pants in t1 for itemC and itemD.

Comment: Even if the user can only ever have 4 items, though, that still depends on the PHP code to stick the right IDs in the right columns.  Absent some constraints in the DB, it can't ensure that you don't have someone wearing two pairs of pants.  :)

Comment: thats what im saying lol! its less flexible by having a column representing the PK of your item. so if you know the person will only ever have 1 shirt 1 socks 1 pants and 1 shorts then it works but if you want to have multiple items for a person then it isnt flexible. If the relation is only ever going to be 1:1 why not just have boolean flags in the person table instead of have a complete new table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the item IDs in `t1`, and `t2` will only ever contain those 4 items, then you could do something like

```
SELECT t2.items
FROM t2
  LEFT JOIN t1 ON (
    (t1.id = :userid) AND
    (t2.id IN (t2.item1, t2.item2, t2.item3, t2.item4))
  )
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

I'd think that should give you rows containing each item that the user with id `:userid` is *not* wearing.

As has been mentioned, though, this is generally a pretty bad way of doing it.  If your 4 items are etched in stone, then `t2` need not exist, and `t1` should have boolean fields that say whether the user has each item.  Otherwise, you'd generally want a table of (user id, item id) rows which determines who's wearing what.  Doing things that way keeps someone from wearing two pairs of pants, for example...and lets you add items at will without having to add columns to your table (which can take a huge amount of time if the table has a lot of rows in it).